# How to fix mysql replication error 1032? Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker

Tags: mysql

Mysql 8.0.28 Replication slave was created multiple times. He started giving the following error. Even though I made stop slave and start slave, the same error continues. how to make slave stand up?

```
Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log , end_log_pos 345612577. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely caused by importing data, then starting replication leading to inconsistent states. Can also be permission issues or whatnot.

To see what was attempted you should do something like this:

```
mysqlbinlog --read-from-remote-server -h <masterip> -u replicateuser <binfile> --verbose --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS -p|grep -A10 -B10 345612577
```

This will give you information on the query that caused the issue.